# how to use a number of figure object of pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, parameters, figure

I really don't get it about the usage of a number of figure object in pyplot.

Let's say I've made two plots with two numbers(1, 2) with plt.figure().

```
plt.figure(1, figsize=(10,4))    
plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)    
plt.bar(category, values)    
plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)    
plt.scatter(category, values)    
plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)    
plt.plot(category, values)    
plt.suptitle('multiple plotting')
plt.show()
```

```
plt.figure(2, figsize=(10,5))    
plt.subplot(3, 1, 1)    
plt.bar(category, values)    
plt.subplot(3, 1, 2)    
plt.scatter(category, values)    
plt.subplot(3, 1, 3)    
plt.plot(category, values)    
plt.suptitle('multiple plotting')
plt.show()
```

Then... What should I do when I want to plot figure 1 again?

I think I could understand how to set a number of a figure, 
But really don't get it when I ca  use it and how to use.

Thank you for the explanation in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would store the handles to the subplots (see example below). In that way you can adress any subplot again later by: `handle.plot(...)`

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(1, figsize=(10,4))
ax1 = plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
ax1.plot(np.random.rand(3,2))
ax2 = plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
ax2.plot(np.random.rand(3,2))
ax3 = plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)
ax3.plot(np.random.rand(3,2))
plt.suptitle('multiple plotting')

ax1.plot(np.random.rand(3,2)) # Plot in first subplot again
ax2.plot(np.random.rand(3,2)) # Plot in second subplot again
plt.show()
```

If you want to use numbers to adress your subplots you can do the following:

```py
fig,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=3,figsize=(10,4))
ax[0].plot(np.random.rand(3,2))
ax[1].plot(np.random.rand(3,2))
ax[2].plot(np.random.rand(3,2))
plt.suptitle('multiple plotting')

ax[0].plot(np.random.rand(3,2))
ax[1].plot(np.random.rand(3,2))
plt.show()
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my question was about the number of figure object not subplots ;)

Comment: you can save the handle to the figure (and adress it later again) in the same way: ```fig1 = plt.figure(1, figsize=(10,4))```

Answer (score 0):

After having called `plt.show()` you cannot plot to those figures again (unless you are in some interactive session(?)). So let's assume you haven't called `plt.show()`. In that case you can reactivate the first figure by `figure(1)`.

```
plt.figure(1, figsize=(10,4))    
plt.plot(...)

plt.figure(2, figsize=(10,5))    
plt.plot(...)

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(...)  # <--- This plots to figure 1 again.

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just by looking the official documentation of `pyplot.figure`, you can instantiate `Figure`, which is:

> The top level container for all the plot elements.

So, a simple way to reuse an instance of figure is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(t):
    return np.exp(-t) * np.cos(2*np.pi*t)
def g(t):
    return np.sin(t) * np.cos(1/(t+0.1))

t1 = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.1)
t2 = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.02)

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(10,4))
fig.suptitle('First figure instance')


plt.figure(2, figsize=(10,5))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.bar(t1, f(t1))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.scatter(t2, g(t2))
plt.suptitle('second plot')
plt.show()

sub1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
sub1.plot(t1, g(t1))
sub2 = fig.add_subplot(224)
sub2.plot(t2, f(t2))
fig.savefig("first_figure.png", dpi=200)
```